# Firefox 27.0.1 Ubuntu, headers in Google Search much too big

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, default-settings

Since Firefox 27.0.1, the Google search headers looks too big (but didn't see any changes on other websites).

Look the difference to Opera (normal):
[image]

**[UPDATE]**
It looks even normal in Chrome:
[image]

Firefox, much too big:
[image]

I didn't change any settings. 
I tried this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-look-wrong-or-appear-differently, didn't change anything.
I tried to change in about:config **layout.css.devPixelsPerPx** from **-1.0** to **1.0**, but nothing.

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**
It seems to be an Ubuntu problem, because in company I had 27.0.1 and not this problem until I got the latest Ubuntu update. Didn't figure out yet how this issue to solve.

**[UPDATE]**
Due to Daniel B's answer, I know it's a design issue by Google. I think the proper way to revert it is to write a negative comment to Google about this crap. I've already done that and I search with ask.com from now on, because Google search is unusable with this "design".

Comment: Google displays websites differently to different users sometimes as a part of their "experiments", the no underline headings look like one of these from experience, does clearing cookies and refreshing help?

Comment: @simonzack has a point. My Win8 laptop (FF) does this, while my Win7 desktop does not (FF). It did coincide with the FF update, but that obviously wasn't universal.

Comment: @simonzack I tried everything described in that link. And it appeared since any update. So anybody changed anything.

Comment: For the record, it looks stupid big in Chrome now as well, especially if you are using a non-standard zoom setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design update by Google, to (sort-of) bring the [mobile search results design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF2Kx.png) to your desktop browsers. [See here.](http://searchengineland.com/google-launch-new-search-results-design-larger-fonts-underlines-soon-185724) Site changes are always rolled out in gradually by Google, so it's perfectly normal for some of your browsers to be affected, while others aren't. They are, as far as Google can tell, different "clients", after all.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Seems that I need to find a solution to get rid of that crap because it's much more difficult to distinguish the search results now.

Comment: Nice find! @Bevor, you can fix it by applying a user-stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug in Opera in the application of CSS rules.

An example google search result for "abc" gives :

[image: google search]

Its HTML is :

[image: html]

Where Firebug sums up the CSS rules as follows :

[image: css rules]

As you can see, two rules apply for font-size, one for 18px and the other for `medium` size.
However, the first one also specifies `!important` which should give it the precedence.
So 18 pixels is the correct font-size.

There are actually quite a few other CSS rules for all the CSS classes mentioned
in the above HTML code that specify font-size, but which get
ignored here because they are of a lower precedence. I have not tried to list them all, but the CSS of Google is really convoluted, which probably throws Opera off.
The CSS precedence rules are quite complicated, but I believe that Firefox gets it right.
Internet Explorer 10 gets the same result as Firefox.

For more info, see :

[What does !important mean in CSS?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)
[Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

**EDIT**

Doing exactly the same thing with Firefox one day later got the font-size of 16 pixels
for exactly the same request, instead of the 18 pixels that I got yesterday.

As my Firefox version is the same, it must be Google that is generating different CSS.

This reinforces the possibility that Google adapts its generated CSS to the browser.
If you multiply this by the number of computers of Google, where it might
take weeks for an update to propagate to all of them, then the result one gets
may be somewhat random.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's an Opera bug, why does it look good in Chrome too? What I don't understand is, why does it look like a css problem, but I've got the problems after an update (on two machines).
This doesn't fit somehow.

Comment: It might be that a Firefox software update has changed the way that CSS rules are evaluated. But see my Edit above : I now suspect Google of being at the root of the problem, adapting its CSS to the browser's version. Google might have got it wrong for Firefox version 27, and in that case one only needs to wait for a few weeks (if one is an optimist).

Comment: Note: If you want a fix now, this will probably require disguising the browser as Opera.